# AJAX login form need browser cookie allowed

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, cookies

I have a laravel project and I wrote a login form with AJAX.

But it returns an error if user's browser doesn't allow cookies.

And many users with safari browser can not login.
How can I fix this?

**Sample Html:**

```
<form id="loginForm" class="validate-form" role="form" method="POST" 
            action="{{ url('/login') }}">
       {{ csrf_field() }}

   Email :
   <input type="text name="email">

   password:
   <input type="password" name="password">

</form>
```

**My JS code:**

```
$modal.find('form').submit(function () {
    $('.login100-form-btn').attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {...},
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {...}
       });
    return false;
});
```

**Part of Laravel LoginController:**

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
     $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
     return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $credentials, $request->has('remember')
    );
 }

protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
            'ok'       => true,
            'success'  => true,
            'intended' => URL::previous(),
        ], 200);
    }

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());

}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a JS problem and not a PHP problem?

Comment: I think we don't have enough information in the question to answer you. However, there is a strong guess here: most login authentifications work with the server giving a cookie to identify the session. If you refuse it, you're not logged. Most people that refuse all cookies should be aware of that already i think, as they cannot log in many sites.

Comment: the code you have posted is not relevant to your issue

Comment: I edited my question @LelioFaieta

Comment: No i'm not sure. I edited the question @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I edited my question @Kaddath

Comment: The information given above is not enough. Check this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-login-with-ajax

Comment: btw, in your $.ajax, $(this) would refer to jQuery and not your form, if you want to access form here, pass the event object to submit's event handler

Comment: you're right. my problem solved.